# Erro com o módulo asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando rodar o exemplo abaixo no IDLE(Python 3.43, Windows 7, 64bits), há dias, mas sempre dá um erro. Tentei buscar solução no site versão inglês, no google, e não encontrei resposta. Eu consigo rodar no Anaconda, mas no IDLE não funciona. Já está instalado o módulo asyncio.
Vou colocar o código e em seguida o erro:

```
import asyncio

def print_and_repeat(loop):
    print('Hello World')
    loop.call_later(2, print_and_repeat, loop)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.call_soon(print_and_repeat, loop)
loop.run_forever()
```

Erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File   "C:\Users\Gustavo\Desktop\asyncio.py", line 1, in <module>  
    import asyncio   File "C:\Users\Gustavo\Desktop\asyncio.py", line 7, in <module>  
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_event_loop'
```

Comment: Aqui na minha máquina rodou normalmente.. estranho. Tanto no console quanto no IDLE. Você chegou a rodar no console? PS: eu tenho a versão 3.4.0 instalada.

Comment: Continuo sem saber. Ao rodar o exemplo, deu erro, mas criou uma pasta com o nome __pycache__.
Dentro dela, eu executei com dois cliques(botão esquerdo) o arquivo asyncio.cpython-34 que foi criado (na execução anterior no IDLE) e ele executou sem erro algum no c:\\Windows\py.exe.
Não sei o que significa, dando erro no arquivo original, e rodando no cache dele.

Answer (score 2):

Se você chamou o seu arquivo de `asyncio.py` ele tem mais prioridade para ser carregado do que o `asyncio` da biblitoeca padrão. (A pasta do arquivo atual sempre fica antes no Python Path).  Assim, quando você faz `import asyncio` está fazendo uma referência ao próprio módulo que está escrevendo (e que não tem a função `get_event_loop`.

Experimente simplesmente renomear seu arquivo para `asyncio_example.py`, por exemplo.

(Ao ler a pergunta, eu desconfiei que esse era o problema e iria colocar a sugestão como comentário - mas você confirmou nos comentários que de fato o seu módulo tem o nome de `asyncio.py`)

Comment: omo uma dica a parte: se vocẽ realemtne vai usar Windows ara desenvolver, sugiro configurar o navegador de arquivos para exibir as extensões de arquivos conhecidos.  É muito importante saber se o arquivo que você está vendo é o ".py", o "pyc", ou o ".pyo"m "py~", etc...

Comment: Sua dica resolveu o problema. Renomeei o arquivo e executou sem erro. Obrigado.

Comment: Se essa é a resposta, lembre-se de marca-la como correta.